# Adobe AIR - FileStream works to save locally but does not fire any event

Tags: actionscript-3, air, save, storage

I am writing a utf file locally in application storage. The file gets written correctly, but no event is fired whatsoever.

```
public static function saveFileToStorage            (path:String, file:*):Boolean { // This savea a ByteArray as a binary or a string as an UTF8 somewhere...
    var f                               :File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(path); 
    // create a file stream
    var fs:FileStream                   = new FileStream();
    fs.addEventListener                 (Event.COMPLETE, onFileSaved); 
    fs.addEventListener                 (Event.CLOSE, onFileSaved); 
    fs.addEventListener                 (IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileSavedError); 
    fs.addEventListener                 (OutputProgressEvent.OUTPUT_PROGRESS, onFileSavedOutputProgress); 
    fs.addEventListener                 (ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onFileSavedProgress); 
    // open the stream for writting
    fs.open                         (f, FileMode.WRITE);
    // write the string data down to the file
    if (file is String)                     fs.writeUTFBytes(file);
    else                                fs.writeBytes(file);
    return                          true;
}
public static function onFileSaved          (e:Event):void {
    Debug.debug                     (_debugPrefix, "File saved successfully.\n"+e);
}
public static function onFileSavedOutputProgress    (e:Event):void {
    Debug.debug                     (_debugPrefix, "File save output progress...\n"+e);
}
public static function onFileSavedProgress          (e:Event):void {
    Debug.debug                     (_debugPrefix, "File save progress...\n"+e);
}
public static function onFileSavedError         (e:Event):void {
    Debug.error                     (_debugPrefix, "File save error.\n"+e);
}
```

File is saved correctly, but NO event is fired... nothing... nada...
this is becoming mysterious...
any hint?

thank you

Comment: Using `open` causes write operations to be synchronous, so no events are fired because the following line will not execute until the write operation completes.   It's a common misunderstanding as `openAsync` isn't used very often in the documentation

Comment: Take a look on [Asynchronous programming and the events generated by a FileStream object opened asynchronously](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7db1.html)

Answer (score -1):

You specifically ask FileStream to not fire any event so why do you expect any to be fired? The question does not make any sense for that reason.

```
FileSteam.open = syncronous and no event fired.
FileStream opanASync = asynchronous and events fired.
```

Comment: Adobe documentation is quite vague on the point. I am not opening, but writing on disk. Opening works as expected. So you mean that it either throw an error at runtime or everything went fine?